# How to write in a diary regularly?

Tags: creative-writing

I have found that I've not been able to continue writing a diary on a regular basis. What tips and tricks are there to help improve and foster the habit of regular diary writing?

Comment: By "diary writing" do you mean "writing down my thoughts and feelings" or "writing down whatever happened today as a way to improve my writing skills"? Those are two different tasks with two different aims.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First :** Habit is something which you like to do with your whole heart.You can't make habits forcefully.

**Second :** What you want to write everyday? Your thoughts,feelings or your daily routine activities. You can easily write about daily activities.But for thoughts and feelings, you can only write about it when you have these things. Suppose If you have no thought or feeling one day or few days,then you can't force yourself to write on that day.

**So there is no tip or trick.It all depends on you, your feelings, your heart**.

Answer (score 0):

Give money to a friend and tell them that they are not to give it back to you unless you can prove you wrote that day. They then give you back a small percentage of the money everyday you write.

Answer (score 0):

I used to write to my diary regularly for seven years. And then the internet happened! It introduced me to a lot of reading material which robbed me of time where I could stay alone with my thoughts long enough to transfer it onto paper. I started writing a blog, later started writing on my laptop and smartphone. Though I did write, it took away the ease with which I could write on paper, to my diary. So, from experience I can tell you that the best way to keep up the habit of maintaining a diary regularly is to cut yourself off from places where you can express your thoughts in the written form, be it Facebook, WhatsApp or even Stack Exchange :P The best way to write great content is to keep talking to yourself throughout the day. This way, by the end of the day, you will have enough thoughts and your opinion of it all that you will be able to pen it down.